# Modifying a Window Class in Tkinter (Python 3)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I've been trying to get to grips with OOP and tkinter in python 3. I'd really like to have sub-windows pop up during use, either for data, output, etc. However, I cannot figure out how to assign the title in my Windows class, depending on what sort of window is being made. Please find a simplified example of what I have done so far.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):

        Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master = master

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):

        self.master.title("ProgramName")

        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)

        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)

        prog_help = Menu(menu)
        prog_help.add_command(label='Help', command=self.help_popup)
        prog_help.add_command(label='About', command=self.version_popup)
        menu.add_cascade(label='Help', menu=prog_help)

    #Method 1: Using message.box
    def version_popup(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("About program", "Version 0.1")
        return

    #Method 2: Using another window
    def help_popup(self):
        helpwindow()
        return

def helpwindow():
    hwindow = Toplevel()
    hwindow.geometry("100x100")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x300")

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I think that I should be doing something in the definition of helpwindow() which alters a variable in self.master.title(x), but I cannot figure out what.

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Since you have 'root' as a global variable, just change 'root.title'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the help window isn't a subclass of anything. All you need to do is call the `title` method of the `Toplevel`

```
def helpwindow():
    hwindow = Toplevel()
    hwindow.title("I am the help window")
    ...
```